# Video.js this.tech undefined firefox

Tags: javascript, html, video, video.js

I'm trying to use BigVideo.js and it works fine in Chrome and Safari however in Firefox the error "this.tech is undefined" shows causing the video not to work. Has anyone had this error before and know of a fix?

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not all video codecs are supported by all browsers. make sure the video format you're trying to broadcast is compatible with firefox

http://dfcb.github.com/BigVideo.js/

> For best results in Firefox, create an Ogg version of your video and
>   configure BigVideo.js as below or in this example. (note: works for
>   WebM also)
>
> ```
> $(function() {
>     var BV = new $.BigVideo({useFlashForFirefox:false});
>     BV.init();
>     BV.show('vids/river.mp4', {altSource:'vids/river.ogv'});
> });
> ```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats has a list of formats each browser supports

Answer (score 2):

Video Online Convert actually does a nice job with WebM

http://video.online-convert.com/convert-to-webm

Or Ogg if you must...

http://video.online-convert.com/convert-to-ogg

You will find it dramatically superior to using .ogv and the plugin very much supports it. for ambient video you would do something more like:

```
var BV = new $.BigVideo({useFlashForFirefox:false});
BV.init();
BV.show('vids/river.mp4', {
  ambient: true,
  altSource:'vids/river.webm'
});
```

Be sure to flag your MP4 as faststart on encoding as well or you'll find it buffers to 100% before IE will start playing it.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error when videojs is instructed to use only Flash, but when Flash is not installed. When using the minified/non-debug version, it also presents as the error message "TypeError: a.h is undefined".